# Tomcat not listening network drive

Tags: jsp, tomcat

In tomcat 7, i am trying access a file which is in **NETWORK DRIVE** and the Network is mapped with my system, Tomcat not listening  Remote file access, May i know what is reason behind in it!

Comment: what do you mean by _Tomcat not listening Remote file access, May i know what is reason behind in it!_ ?

Comment: i am trying to access a file which is in client system, so i mapped it as a Network drive , Now i couldn't get the file in mapped drive  via tomcat, it showing exception

Comment: Reason behind what? Make up your mind first. Is Tomcat not listening at a port? is it unable to access a network drive? is your *client* unable to access a network drive? These are all different things, not the same thing. Which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get access the `network derives` if your system is secured by `Firewall`

You have two options to implement this,

- Disable `Firwall`
- Use tomcat executable installation not `archive formats(zip)`